# Dropdown sublist acting wierd

Tags: html, css

I have a problem which my child's ul li wont act as they should based on what I've seen on other places.
I followed enough threads to create that question and I have been debugging for more than 3 days and I cant point out the problem.
The image explains the problem great:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOrjD.jpg

```
<nav id="main-nav" class="main-nav">
               <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Dropdown &darr; </a>
                         <ul id="sublist">
                              <li><a href="#">Tomorrow</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Doomoro</a></li>
                         </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
               </ul>
          </nav>
```

css:

```
nav ul li a {
font-family:'Cookie', cursive;
background-color:#400000 ;

border-radius: 0.5em;
color:#fff;
display:block;
line-height:3em;
text-align:center;
text-decoration:none;
width:100%;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color:#680000 ;
    color:white;
}

nav ul li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 48px;

}

nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;

}
nav ul li:hover li {
    float: none;
}

#sublist li a {
    font-family:'Cookie', cursive;
    background-color:#400000 ;

    border-radius: 0.3em;
    color:#fff;
    display:block;
    line-height:3em;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    width:100%;
}
```

---

Clarifications: the 'a' element is the smaller one.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: You have CSS code that is not in the question ... I did [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/puzepe/1/edit) to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cy3vsndu/3/). There were a few things missing from your CSS which I've added. The HTML remains the same and here's the new CSS code:

```
#main-nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
ul#sublist li {
    display: block;
}
ul#sublist {
    padding-left: 6px;
    top: 84px;
}
nav ul li a {
    font-family:'Cookie', cursive;
    background-color:#400000;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    color:#fff;
    display:block;
    line-height:3em;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    width:100%;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color:#680000;
    color:white;
}
nav ul li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 48px;
}
nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 1;
}
nav ul li:hover li {
    float: none;
}
#sublist li a {
    font-family:'Cookie', cursive;
    background-color:#400000;
    border-radius: 0.3em;
    color:#fff;
    display:block;
    line-height:3em;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Well, it does look better on jsfid. On my page its abit wider now, thats all. Thanks for trying anyway.

Comment: You missed adding the `display: inline-block;` property to the CSS of `#main-nav ul li`, the `display: block;` property to the CSS of `ul#sublist li` and apart from this, I added a little padding to `nav ul li a`.

Comment: As I said before, things look better on jsfiddle, mayb the problem is somewhere else in my code. Should I post the full code?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are reseting your style using [CSS box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)  and removing padding and margin, then set the left position on the `ul ul element`

`*{box-sizing:border-box;padding:0; margin:0}`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kougiland/nwoo9ja6/)

```
*{box-sizing:border-box;padding:0; margin:0}
nav{position:relative;}
nav ul{max-width:480px;margin:40px auto}
nav li{list-style:none; float:left;position:relative}
nav ul li a {
font-family:'Cookie', cursive;
background-color:#400000 ;
border-radius: 0.5em;
color:#fff;
display:block;
line-height:3em;
text-align:center;
text-decoration:none;
padding:6px 12px;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color:#680000 ;
    color:white;
}

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left:0
}

nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;

}
nav ul li:hover li {
    float: none;
}

#sublist li a {
    font-family:'Cookie', cursive;
    background-color:#400000 ;

    border-radius: 0.3em;
    color:#fff;
    display:block;
    line-height:3em;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: My sublime does not like the "box-sizing:border-box" line. We're getting closer.

Comment: @YanivMor then remove it and add `padding:0` to `ul ul `  here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/kougiland/nwoo9ja6/2/